# Make MyFunction() trigger every minute

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have this C# code and I want it to trigger every minute.

```
private void MyFunction()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 6 && ranalarm == false)
    {
        ranalarm = true;
        Event();
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Hour != 6 && ranalarm == true)
    {
        ranalarm = false;
    }
}
```

How can I make function `MyFunction()` trigger every minute in C#?
I tried working with timers but Visual Studio said it conflicted with my `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: Uhhm, what about `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: How you create instance of Timer class and how you call Tick event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2). Something like this:

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Zero;
TimeSpan minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(c =>
{
    MyFunction();
}, null, start, minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. No use of threading. Simple easy but gets the job done

```
Timer testTimer;

public void initTimer()
{
    testTimer = new Timer();
    testTimer.Tick += testTimer_tick ;
    testTimer.Interval = 1000; //timer interval in mili seconds;
    testTimer.Start();
}

public void testTimer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    MyFunction(); // your function comes here           
}
```

You can just copy this and paste.
Next just call the `initTimer()` method in form load event.