# ASP.NET Timer do not work. How to call function every X seconds?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I am creating a page in ASP.NET Framework and I need to update text in Label every X seconds. I tried to create new `Thread` and call `Thread.Sleep()`, but it do not work, Everything what is written bellow Thread.Sleep do not execute, I do not know why. So I found on internet Timer. I created Timer and it do not call method. If I write it statically to .aspx it works:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
     <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="5000" ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="DateStampLabel" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

This works, but I want to change time, so I created it dynamically in C#:

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Tick += UpdateTimer_Tick;
            timer.Interval = 2000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
```

But `UpdateTimer` has never been called. So I tried this and it still do not work:

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer();
            timeoutTimer.ID = "timeouttimer";
            timeoutTimer.Interval = 10000;
            timeoutTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(UpdarteTimer_Tick);


            UpdatePanel timerUpdatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
            timerUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(timeoutTimer);


            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(timeoutTimer);


            this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(timerUpdatePanel);
        }


        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

I really need this on my website. Please help me. How can I create some routine in ASP.NET? Why I can't use Thread.Sleep in website and why is my timer do not work? Thank you

Comment: Similar? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52800865/2946329

Comment: Have you considered doing this client side (in JS) instead?

Comment: @SalahAkbari Thanks, but it do not work, method was called only one time at the launch of page

Comment: @mjwills I do not know JS

Comment: I'd strongly suggest spending some time learning it.

Answer (score 0):

After setting timer properties you have to call this line to start the timer:

```
timer.Start();
```

**UPD:**
I checked your UI timer and It works but It reload page every time when tick event happens.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

and in the code behind file:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Thus, I recommend using js method which I mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Thank you, I know I have to call Start(), but Timer do not contain method Start()

Comment: Which timer do you use? from which library?

Comment: From System.Web.UI, I know there is also System.Timers.Timer, but it have different constructor and do not contain Tick

Comment: I copied your code and below comment I add this: Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();, but TimerTick() have been called only onetime when page load and then not

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the interval of the Timer on Page.. you can just reference the one already created and set the Interval in either Page_Init or Page_Load like this ...

```
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
     <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="5000" ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick"  />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="DateStampLabel" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UpdateTimer.Interval = 2000;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok, you can use js code

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            WebForm_GetElementById("MainContent_Label1").textContent = new Date().toLocaleString();
        }, 1000);
    });

</script>
```

Pay attention that Label ID and element name which you are looking for are different! (Honestly, I don't know why ASP.NET changes that ID)